# Django Wagtail adding classname to structblock

Tags: django, wagtail

I have a structblock as below:

```
 image = StructBlock([
        ('file', ImageChooserBlock()),
        ('caption', RichTextBlock( classname='caption'  )),

    ])
```

But on the frontend template {{item.value.caption}} produces a div with class 'rich-text'.

Am I missing something?

I am using wagtail 1.13 with django 1.11.6 ( python 3.6 )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `classname` keyword argument on a block only affects the form field as displayed within the Wagtail admin - it doesn't have any effect on the front-end template rendering.

The `<div class="rich-text">` element around rich text is hard-coded and can't be customised - if you need a custom class name, it's suggested that you add an extra wrapper element around it on your template, and apply styles based on that.